# NoSQL Document oriented storage alternatives to use with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, nosql

I'm new in the .NET and Xamarin world's. Currently I'm work in the migration of an app developed in an hybrid approach to Xamarin.Forms. The data handled by this app has not a fixed structure (schema-free).

In the current hybrid application these data are stored in a SQLite database as string and parsed to JSON when necessary (a not good nor elegant approach).

In the new implementation of this app I would like to store and handle my data using a document oriented data layer (lets say, a "embedded" NoSQL database, like MongoDB).

Searching in the web I found some options:

- http://www.marcellodb.org/
- http://www.iboxdb.com/
- http://www.litedb.org/
- https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-net

But these alternatives seems to me not sufficiently mature or PCL compatible.

**My question is:** what are the mature embedded alternatives to store data in a Xamarin.Forms PCL application that uses a document oriented approach (like mongoDB)?

Reports of actual experiences with these tools will be very appreciated too.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at LexDB

https://github.com/demigor/lex.db

or SIAQODB (not free)

https://www.siaqodb.com/

Comment: Hi! I accepted your answer because SIAQODB proved to be the most appropriate for my use case. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I believe Couchbase is mature enough and if you want a NoSQL db, this might be your best option, also it works well with Xamarin.Forms as you can see [here](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/ToDoLite-Xamarin-Forms)

Comment: Oh, yes. But this project uses a SAP approach, not a PCL, right?

Comment: you are right mate, I didn't know that, and they said that they will probably have PCL compatibility in Net Standard 2.0 , so that might be a problem for now, [link](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-lite-net-xamarin-pcl-compatibility/10405/2)

Answer (score 2):

A very good NoSQL database very easy to use for this purpose is LiteDB, and it is built in C# and very similar to MongoDB, it is stand alone, portable and works like a charm on Xamarin.Forms, [Check this detailed tutorial I made on using LiteDB on Xamarin.Forms](https://doumer.me/litedb-on-xamarin-forms-alternative-to-sqlite/)